# Display form result same page with form

Tags: php, html, concrete5

I am developing a function which imports data from CSV file into a website. (Users, products and etc..), however, some CSV files are too big, like CSV file for Products which have 15000+ lines, event all I need to do is put each line in array than call a function from CMS to same it in database it was till takes too long, so the page even I changed the excitation time on server still will show lost contention after a while, so I decided to display a results message every time after one product has been imported.

I have file called importedFiles.php which analysed CSV file and do importing.
added following code so result will display real-time:

```
set_time_limit(0); 
ob_end_clean(); 
ob_implicit_flush(1);
```

In my foreach loop, I have this

```
     foreach ($arrays as $p) {
        Groups::add($p['groupName'], $p['pfID']);// add function
        $rowsUpdated = $rowsUpdated + 1;
        echo $p['groupName'] . "::" . "has been added to database" . "<br>";
      }

    }
```

In my view file `Store_bulk_import.php`

```
<form id="import-form" action="" method="post">
  <h2>Community Store Bulk Import</h2>
  <hr />
  <fieldset>
    <legend>1. Select a file for update products</legend>
    <div class="help-block">Import files must be in CSV format.</div>
    <?php
    echo $al->file('ccm-b-file', 'fileID', t('Choose File'), $csvFile);
    ?>
  </fieldset>
  <br />
  <input id="import-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Import Products" style="" />
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  ?>
  <div class="container">
    <?php
    $csvfile = $_POST['fileID'];
    echo $controller->csvImport($csvfile) . "<br>";    
     ?>
  </div>
```

Results will display out side of the area I want will display most of them on top of the page even before some of the CMS content have been loaded.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is HTML before ob_end_clean() you should call [ob_end_flush()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) instead.
ob_end_clean discards all output, so all your HTML until that point is lost.

In addition if there is any HTML after the `</div>` in your code, it will not be sent until your import finished, this could also destroy your layout.

Comment: Yes you are right, when i use ob_end_flush(), it is display in right position but all the styles file and script file are not loaded

Comment: You should inspect the HTML in your browser to see what important parts are missing. It's strange that the script and style files are not loaded, are they in the `<head>` part?